# How to set ticks after log scale in Seaborn FacetGrid?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to plot a FacetGrid consisting of histograms with a log transformation on the y axis. Im unable to set the yticks to a more readable format.

```
ticks = [0.1, 0.3, 1, 3, 10, 30, 100, 300, 1000, 3000, 10000]
labels = [i for i in ticks]
grid = sns.FacetGrid(data = df, col = 'LoanStatus', col_wrap = 4)
grid.map(plt.hist, 'credit_score_range_average', bins = 20).set(yscale ='log', yticks = (ticks, labels))
```

I receive a Value Error: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().
[image]

[image]

Setting yticks = (ticks, labels) is how I achieve this in matplotlib.

***while writing this and trying some last options, I went with a sns.distplot and found it to be much better option for my case. I would still appreciate any insight in this issue***

Comment: Usually the error traceback (not just the last line of it) gives valuable insight into any issue. You may post it here, as well as a [mcve] (i.e. runnable code).

Comment: added. Forgive the small text. When attempting set yticks = ticks alone, the code runs but does not produce the desired effect.

Comment: I see; I suppose you meant to write `.set(yscale ='log', yticks = ticks, yticklabels=labels)`?

Comment: hmm, so that runs but still isn't applying the proper ticks. I never knew that was a parameter though so I'm sure it will be useful in the future.

Comment: If you want to provide some runnable code, I can try to see where the issue lies.

Comment: found a working solution with your help and some trial and error, see my solution. Thanks for leading me the right direction.

Answer (score 13):

I've finally found this solution to work. Strangely you must call grid.set() again on a new line. Hope this saves someone some time. You can NOT include the yscale argument in this line either or else it will fail.

```
ticks = [0.1, 0.3, 1, 3, 10, 30, 100, 300, 1000, 3000, 10000, 30000]
labels = [i for i in ticks]
grid = sns.FacetGrid(data = df, col = 'LoanStatus', col_wrap = 4)
grid.map(plt.hist, 'credit_score_range_average').set(yscale = 'log')
grid.set(yticks = ticks, yticklabels = labels)
```

[image]

Comment: Ah this is not as strange as it may seem. If you set the scale it will overwrite the locator and formatter. So you necessarily need to set the ticks and labels **after** setting the scale. This cannot be guaranteed if they are within the same `.set`.